# mod_rewrite Cannot redirect without rewriting url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to another server application running on a different port of the same box with apache HTTPD as the frontend server running on port 80. I'm using the rewrite engine and the following syntax to redirect calls:

```
RewriteRule ^/?products/(.*)$ http://www.example.com:9000/$1 [L]
```

This works great, but the url changes to port 9000 in the browser. Whenever I change the `[L]` to a `[P]` for proxy I get a 404, not found error in the browser.

How do I fix this so that the url doesn't change in the browser, but that it still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have mod_proxy loaded, otherwise the `P` flag won't work.

You can also use the `ProxyPass` directive as part of mod_proxy in your vhost config.

Comment: How do I load mod_proxy?

Comment: @Jason depends on the linux distro or the OS, but generally you want a line like this in httpd.conf: `LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`

Comment: This was the issue. On ubuntu server I was able to do: `a2enmod proxy_http`